# jquery datepicker pass variable from one function to another

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i'm trying to pass the data i got from the function initiated by onChangeMonthYear to the function initiated by beforeShowDay. I tried various methods, like assigning the data I got from test.php to a variable declared at the outside but to no avail.  so what i did was just update a text field with the retrieved data from test.php, and asks the function in beforeShowDay to get the data from there. here's a portion of my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', currentText: 'Now', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, altField: '#alternate', altFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy', onSelect:  function(dateText, inst) {}, 
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year,month,inst){
            $.post("test.php", {action: "TEST", month: month, year: year}, 
            function (data){
                $("#datafromphp").val(data);
            }
            ,"html");
        }, 
        beforeShowDay: function (date){
            var getdatafromphp= $("#datafromphp").val();

        }
    });
});
```

surely there's a better way to do this?

Comment: You said you tried to assign the data "to a variable declared at the outside but to no avail" - what happened when you tried to do that?

Comment: function in beforeShowDay don't get i - it's empty. at least that's what's the function thinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to grab some data via AJAX asynchronously in `onChangeMonthYear` and make it accessible in `beforeShowDay` in order to display the updated data.

It helps to understand the order of the calls. When the calendar first appears, a bunch of calls are made to `beforeShowDay`. At this stage, there is no data from your AJAX call yet (i.e. from `test.php`).

Once the user changes the month/year, `onChangeMonthYear` will be called, and a bunch of calls are then made to `beforeShowDay` again. At this stage, there should still be no data from your AJAX call, unless the AJAX call to `test.php` manages to return quickly enough for some of the calls to  `beforeShowDay` to access the returned value.

Then the AJAX call returns and the returned data is somehow passed to `beforeShowDay` to display.

As you can see, what you tried to do would not work, as the AJAX call would not be on time for `beforeShowDay` to grab the data even if you "pass" it correctly. What you want to do is, assign the returned data from AJAX somewhere, and then refresh the datepicker, so `beforeShowDay` would be called again. You can store data to an arbitrary jQuery object with `.data()`. So, you can do something like this:

```
$('#datepicker').data('datafromphp', []).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', currentText: 'Now', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, altField: '#alternate', altFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy', onSelect:  function(dateText, inst) {}, 
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year,month,inst){
        $.post("test.php", {action: "TEST", month: month, year: year}, 
        function (data){
            $("#datepicker").data('datafromphp', data).datepicker('refresh');
        }
        ,"html");
    }, 
    beforeShowDay: function (date){
        var getdatafromphp= $(this).data("datafromphp");

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation william; btw i made changes to my code, and now the php calls returns a json encoded data (array), and it seems that by doing `var getdatafromphp= $(this).data("datafromphp");` it doesn't treat the received data as array..

Comment: i made changes to my code, and now the php calls returns a json encoded data (array), and it seems that by doing `var getdatafromphp= $(this).data("datafromphp");` it doesn't treat the received data as array.. i get this conclusion because if I do `alert(data.length)` inside the onChangeMonthYear function, it will return the length of the array, but if i put `alert(getdatafromphp.length)` it will return an error (getdatafromphp is undefined)

Comment: That's because `beforeShowDay` would be called first, before `$(this).data("datafromphp")` is set. If you want to avoid that, just initiate the data to an empty array. See updated answer...